# Magento Web Hook

Tags: magento2

I am planing to create a web hook in `Magento` through which `Magento` will send a alert to the destination upon placing an order using web hook.

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Comment: no I still searching :(

Comment: Please my answer

Comment: how can open module in ui of admin magento 2

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148387)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148387)

Answer (score 4):

First thing there is no `web hooks` available in Magento.
Magento call them **Event Observer**.

**What is an Event:** An event can be any action Or state in magento like `customer_register_success`, `sales_order_place_after` etc.

**What is an Observer:** An Observer is a PHP class which listen to events, when events get fire Observer class get activated.

For example we need order details when order get placed.We are going to create a custom module for this say `Pawanist_Orderdata`

Create following files for module:

> app/code/Pawanist/Orderdata/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Pawanist_Orderdata',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Pawanist/Orderdata/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pawanist_Orderdata" setup_version="1.0.1">
   </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawanist/Orderdata/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="sales_pawanist_orderdata" instance="Pawanist\Orderdata\Observer\GetOrderData" />
</event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawanist/Orderdata/Observer/GetOrderData.php

```
<?php

namespace Pawanist\Orderdata\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class GetOrderData implements ObserverInterface
{
 protected $logger;

 public function __construct(LoggerInterface$logger) {
 $this->logger = $logger;
 }

 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
    try {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $total = $order->getGrandTotal();//this will log order total
        $this->logger->info($total);

    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

After creating module, you need to activate module using:

```
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (only required in production mode)
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: Instead of writing log ,I want to send data on a specific url.

Comment: What data you want to send and on which URL ?

Comment: I want to send Order releated info

Comment: As in answer I get grand total, you can find other order data. If you want to send to URL, you can use Curl. example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-a-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Magento Observer feature here and use event **sales_order_place_after**

You can follow this link to implement this
https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-order-data-from-magento-2-sales_order_place_after-event/

Answer (score 0):

Try this Webhook module https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-webhook/
After creating order, it will send a hook request to any endpoints.

Comment: but its not support with order status with multiple endpoints.

Comment: it used to be a free module; now it costs $229(!)